# MacOS Automator: Save new text file in current folder

Tags: automator, folders

I am trying to write a simple Automator service to merge selected text files. I’ve nearly got it, but I am running into one problem.

I want to create a new text file from the combined output of the selected files. When I add the `New Text File` action, I can only set the `Where` location to a particular folder.

If I want to create a new folder, I have the option of `Same Folder as Input`. This does not appear for new text files.

How can I save a new text file to the same folder as the selected files?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the workflow and which version of OS X/macOS are you using.

Comment: @user3439894 It seems that we’re in different time zones — thanks for the answer below. FWIW, it’s MacOS 10.12.5 Sierra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you did not include your *workflow*, what *type* of *workflow* it is, or which version of OS X/macOS you're using, I can only offer an *example* of how you can set a *variable* to use for the **Where:** in a **New Text File** *action* in an **Automator** *workflow*.

I have a **Temp** folder, which I created, in the *root* the **Macintosh HD**, and in this folder I created two plain text files, named **Filename1.txt** and **Filename2.txt**, each of which contain a single line of text, "*The name of this file is Filename1.txt*" and "*The name of this file is Filename2.txt*", respectively.

The following **Automator** *workflow* works with *selected* **Finder** items in **Finder's** frontmost window, or the **Desktop** as appropriate if no other individual **Finder** windows are frontmost with a *selection*, and using a **Run AppleScript** *action* sets a *variable* to the *parent* folder of the *first item selected* to be used as the **Where:** in a **New Text File** *action*. and creates a file named **Combined.txt**.

Note in the image below, there is a break in the link between the **Set Value of Variable** *action* and what is the second **Get Selected Finders Item** *action*.  This disconnect is created by selecting **Ignore this action's input** under **Options** in the second **Get Selected Finders Item** *action*.

The *variable* `inputParentFolder` was *dragged* and *dropped* from the **Variable** section at the bottom of the *workflow pane* into the **Where:** in the **New Text File** *action*.

As you can see in the image below, the *workflow* completed successfully combining the content of the two *selected* files in **Finder** into a new file named **Combined.txt** in the same folder as the *selected* files.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. The key parts for my problem were: (a) the AppleScript to get the parent folder, (b) saving this into a variable, (c) using this variable in the `Where` property (I didn’t know you could do that), and (d) getting the finder items _again_ to do the merge. I do think the process would have been simpler if they simply included the option of __Current Folder__ …

Comment: @Manngo, Yes, it would be a whole lot easier if the **New Text File** _action_ had **Same Folder as Input** as a choice in the **Where:** _list_, like it does in the **New Folder** _action_. However, at least there is a workaround to achieve the goal.