# Right Click for New Text File on Mac OS

Tags: mac, finder, applescript, automator

I am looking for the way to create a new text file When I right click.

When I right click on an empty area in the Finder, I want an option called "Create New Text File" in the menu. But When I right click on a file in Finder, I want two options called "Create New Text File"  and "Create Text File as the Same Name of the file" in the menu.

Is it possible?

Comment: [This answer is one I particularly like once you want a couple items to be templated.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277069/5472) and that one [covers how to process the name of a selected file for your second question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/290878/5472).